# Where to find all culture specific CultureInfo string comparison rules?

Tags: c#, windows, cultureinfo, rules, culture

I am curious to find out what the string comparison rules for my culture (`ru-ru`) are. I tried to search for a full list of rules and settings for every culture, but found only lists of names and, for example, datetime formats. Tried to look at source code of .NET, found that everything is populated by external method `CultureData.nativeInitCultureData`. Without any documentation.

For example, I know that in `de-de` culture these words are equal: `straße`, `strasse`. In `tr-tr`, there are diffrernt uppercase and lowercase variants for "I" and "i" and they affect string comparison. Where do these rules come from and where can I get the comprehensive list?